# Wait until animation completes to run the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have this code:

```
$("div#element").hide("fast");
$("div#aelement-2").show("fast");
```

How can I make `#aelement-2` fade in *after* `#aelement` has faded out?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want `element-2` to wait until `element` has finished? Or do you want them to start and finish at the same time? Do you want the `element-2` to fade in and stop once `element` has finished fading out - irrelevant of how far along `element-2` is in its fade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand your question, but you can use callbacks:

```
$("div#element").hide("fast", function() {
    $("div#aelement-2").show("fast");
});
```

This will not start showing `#aelement-2` until `#element` has done animating.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/hide/

`.hide( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`

The `callback` parameter is your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/f8key/1/

You can use delay()

```
$("#d1").hide('fast');
$("#d2").delay('fast').show('fast');
```

Reference:  http://api.jquery.com/delay/